# Time period for small vertical oscillations of bob

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, oscillators, elasticity

We have a small bob attached to an elastic rubber wire and we are given values of the wire’s Young’s modulus, length, and area. My doubt is not to know the answer specifically, just to review my  process.

My thought is we have to find the time period of small oscillation of bob only up to it goes downward and comes back to the equilibrium position. In the upward half it will not show simple harmonic motion. The elasticity of rubber will act only when it expands, so we calculate the general height acquired by using simple kinematics.

But in the answer they considered SHM in upward half also. Am I wrong or is the answer wrong? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

> But in the answer they considered SHM in upward half also.

Whoever wrote the answer is apparently considering the elastic rubber wire to be compressible as well  as stretchable. If you don’t agree, you could solve for the period both ways, to demonstrate that you understand both situations.

Comment: But similar To this question i saw a question with a rubber cord there they considered it’s effect only in expansion but not in compression although it’s true

Comment: Consistency is not everyone’s strong point.

Comment: Means I am preparing for exam so I don’t  want do mistake in exam that’s why I want to know what is correct

Comment: Is it multiple choice? Most likely only one of the possible answers will be offered.

Comment: It is integer type